# Reading multiple files with FileReader and getting array of the filedatas

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, filereader

So I have FileList of files and I need to read them all to an array ie. `[fileData1, fileData2]`, so that I can make a request with all the files to my backend. I'm stuck with all the async opertions and am not sure how to wait for things to finish. I need a way to detect when I can make the request to the backend. I also want to make this in a functional way of programming. Sorry if the question is unclear.

```
files.map((file) => {
        const fr = new FileReader();

        fr.readAsDataURL(file)

        fr.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
            // This is what I need to get to an array
            const fileData = event.target.value.substr(fr.result.indexOf(',') + 1);

        })
    })
//Here I need to make a single post request with all the files in it
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you added the `functional-programming` tag, how about a good old fashioned recursive function:

```
function read_files(cur_file) {
    if (cur_file < files.length) {
        // read the next file
        const fr = new FileReader();
        fr.readAsDataURL(files[cur_file]);
        fr.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
            // extract the file data from event here
            read_files(cur_file+1);
        }
    }
    else {
        // we've read all the files
        // send the request
    }
}

read_files(0);
```

Comment: cur_file counter kinda breaks the immutability rule of functional-programming. Aside that, how would one extract the file to outside of the load function, without using global var.

Comment: @user2933157 You are right about `cur_file`, the is not reason for it to be a global var, I changed my code. As for the second question, you could add an array as an argument to `read_files` and accumulate the data there.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this tomorrow when I have a chance to test it.